# Python 3.11 no encuentra mi módulo psycopg2

Tags: python, pip

Quiero importar el modulo **psycopg2** para poder trabajar con ella con el framework **Django** y al llamar al modulo ocurre el siguente error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Intenté importarlo en un script aparte y devolvió lo siguente:

```
import psycopg2
```

```
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

Estoy intentando importar la librería psycopg2 con:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

y también probé con:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Los 2 métodos muestran haberse instalado de la manera correcta.
Pero al intentar importarlo sale el error ya dicho.

Probé instalándolo desde Anaconda y ocurre lo mismo.

```
conda install psycopg2-binary
```

y

```
conda install psycopg2
```

Instalé variedad de compiladores de C++ por si fallaba en la compilación:

[Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

y

[downloading Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución fue eliminar manualmente las carpetas de
`psycopg2` desde:

```
anaconda3\Lib\site-packages.
```

Al parecer había instalado diferentes versiones de la misma librería.

Comment: No es recomendable que uses en el mismo entorno paquetes instalados con conda y con pip. Conda es capaz de detectar paquetes instalado con pip, pero no al revés. Al borrar el paquete de conda manualmente, acabas de alterar la instalación de anaconda y puede darte muchos problemas. Deberías haber desinstalado el paquete usando conda. Por otro lado, aprende a usar entornos virtuales para evitar que la instalación de paquetes altere tu entorno anaconda base.